# Add a underscore to every regexp match in linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Given 100 XML files that can contain UUIDs I want to find all UUIDs and add an underscore to the beginning of that UUID. The content of the XML file can look different but an example is:

```
<bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="627b6548-aa19-47c6-a87c-31017810a934-_jbpm-unique-3490" >
```

I want to transform this to:

```
<bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="_627b6548-aa19-47c6-a87c-31017810a934-_jbpm-unique-3490" >
```

What I have so far is a regexp to find all UUIDs:

```
ag [0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

The problem is that most other articles I have found either is for how to start the line that contains a match with some character or to replace the whole line. I just want to add a character to the match.

Comment: You know the thing about using regex for XML? [ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct. You can use that in `sed` as:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}/_&/g' file
```

Replacement expression `_&` will prefix matched text with underscore.